# Table of Contents with "Chapter" and per-chapter "Appendix"

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

How do I create a table of contents that looks like:

```
Chater 1 Name

   1.1 section
   1.2 section 
   Appendix A
   Appendix B

Chapter 2 Name

   2.1 section
   2.2 section 
   Appendix A
   Appendix B
```

Specifically, I am wondering how to create appendix entries for each chapter, instead of the whole document. I am also wondering how to add the terms "Appendix" and "Chapter" as shown above.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It would help if you provided a bit more information on (i) the document class you're currently using and (ii) all formatting-relevant issues you need to satisfy (such as font size, bold and/or italic font usage, and the width of the text block). Separately, do you want the chapter-specific appendices to be "numbered" as `A`, `B`, etc or as `1.A`, `1.B`, `2.A`, `2.B`, etc?

Comment: I am using the report documentclass. I am not too picky on the font size or numbering, mainly just the indendation.

Comment: A follow-up question: Do you just want to display "Appendix A", etc, or do the appendix sections have their separate header strings?

Comment: I would like them to have separate header stings--whatever the name of the chapter/section/subsection/etc. Thanks for following up.

Comment: The subappendices environment in the appedix allows appexices within a chapter but not the formatting I was hoping for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the following code does most of what you're asking for. Be sure to use the macro `\appsecnums` in each chapter at the start of the appendix area.

The major (but hopefully not disqualifying) limitation of this code is that you can't have subsections (or subsubsections) inside appendix-type sections because the numbering would be incorrect. (Specifically, you'd have an unwanted "Appendix" string prefixed to the sub(sub)section's number.) When cross-referencing an appendix section labelled, say, as `\label{sec:newapp}`, be sure to write `\ref{sec:newapp}` rather than `Appendix~\ref{sec:newapp}`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft} % the tocloft package lets you redefine the Table of Contents (ToC)
  \renewcommand\cftchappresnum{Chapter } % prefix "Chapter " to chapter number in ToC
  \cftsetindents{chapter}{0em}{8em}      % set amount of indenting
  \cftsetindents{section}{2em}{6em}
% Macros to redefine numbering of appendix sections (and to
%   reset numbering when not in per-chapter area appendix)
\newcommand\normalsecnums{%
    \renewcommand\thesection{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}}
\let\origchapter\chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}[1]{\normalsecnums
    \origchapter{#1}}
\newcommand\appsecnums{%   % execute this command before entering appendix area
    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \renewcommand\thesection{\appendixname~\Alph{section}}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{Section Title}
\section{Section Title}
\appsecnums  % switch to "appendix-style" numbering of sections
\section{Some additional stuff}
\section{Still more additional stuff}

\chapter{Another Chapter}
\section{Section Title}
\section{Section Title}
\appsecnums  % switch to "appendix-style" numbering of sections
\section{Some additional stuff}
\section{Still more additional stuff}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum.** In the MWE above, to change the numbering style of the appendices from `A`, `B`, ... to `<chapnum>.A`, `<chapnum>.B`, ..., you'd need to modify the instruction

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\appendixname~\Alph{section}}}
```

as follows:

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\appendixname~\thechapter.\Alph{section}}}
```

You'll probably also need to increase the indent amount, in the third argument of `cftsetindents` commands, by a bit, say by 0.75em:

```
\cftsetindents{chapter}{0em}{8.75em}  
\cftsetindents{section}{2em}{6.75em}
```

Comment: This is great. You see this format in books quite often. What about if someone wanted to make it look like:

Chapter 1   First Chapter

    1.1     Section Title
    1.2     Section Title

    Appendix

    1.A     Appendix Title
    1.B     Appendix Title

Comment: @AlexRichter: Please see the addendum to my answer.

Comment: In my response, I wasn't able to show formatting. Perhaps you could take a look at the other question I posted to see better what I mean. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @AlexRichter: I've noticed your new question in the meantime and have attempted to provide a more directed answer there.

Answer (score 5):

You can do the following. It uses `\section*` to place the Appendix. Notice that  you have to use special new command `\Appx` for that. Package `amsmath` is loaded to provide the command `\numberwithin`.

EDIT: Modified the command `\l@chapter` that is responsible for printing the chapter entries in ToC so that they include the chapter name.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter

% Per-section appendicies
\newcounter{Appx}
\numberwithin{Appx}{chapter}
\def\@Appx[#1]#2{
\refstepcounter{Appx}
\section*{%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\appendixname\ \Alph{Appx}\quad#1}%
\appendixname\ \Alph{Appx}\quad#2}
}
\def\@@Appx#1{\@Appx[#1]{#1}}
\def\Appx{\@ifnextchar[\@Appx\@@Appx}

% "Chapter" prefix in ToC
\let\@@l@chapter\l@chapter
\def\l@chapter#1{\@@l@chapter{\chaptername\ #1}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{CHP}
\section{SEC}
\section{SECC}
\Appx{APX}
\Appx{APXX}

\chapter{CHP}
\section{SEC}
\section{SECC}
\Appx{APX}
\Appx{APXX}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use the `etoolbox` package to patch the `\@chapter` command to include the word "Chapter" in the ToC (another option would be to use the `tocloft` package).

Comment: I have done in another way, I forgot that original poster asked for that as well.