# Display \chaptername in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, tocloft

I'm looking for something to resolve the problem that has been metioned at [How do I get \chaptername to appear in the table of contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3397/how-do-i-get-chaptername-to-appear-in-the-table-of-contents)  and [Table of Contents with “Chapter” and per-chapter “Appendix”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46920/table-of-contents-with-chapter-and-per-chapter-appendix/56770#comment119029_56770) threads.

Those is exactly what I'm looking for. But I've got error when as soon as using

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
```

And here is the error messenge:

> ! LaTeX Error: Command \c@lofdepth already defined.
>                  Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
>   Type  H   for immediate help.
>   l.597   \newcounter{lofdepth} \setcounter{lofdepth}{1}

Please tell me what is that error! And how to fix?

My .cls file contain:

```
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{
\btypeout{Contents}
\addtotoc{Contents}
\begin{spacing}{1}{
\setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
   \if@twocolumn
     \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
   \else
     \@restonecolfalse
   \fi
   \chapter*{\contentsname
    \@mkboth{
       \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}
   \@starttoc{toc}
   \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
   \cleardoublepage
  }\end{spacing}
}
```

And because there is error occured when I've tried using the tocloft package. So I have used the following code block:

```
\makeatletter
\let\@@l@chapter\l@chapter
\def\l@chapter#1{\@@l@chapter{\chaptername\ #1}}
\makeatother
```

But the result is not as well as my wish. It's look like this:

> Chapter List of tables
>   .....
>   Chapter List of figures
>   Chapter 1 Introduction
>      The chapter 1 contents table.
>   ....
>   Chapter A Examples

But what I wanna is something like this:

> List of tables
>   List of figures
>
> Chapter 1 Introduction
>   ...
>   Chapter 2 And so on...
>   Appendix A

Anyone can give me some suggestion? Thanks avandce!

Comment: Can you add a MWE to reproduce the error?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The error you are getting comes from loading the `tocloft` and `subfigure` packages simultaneously, as the following example swhows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}

test

\end{document}
```

As soon as one processes this document, the following error shows up:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \c@lofdepth already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.124 \newcounter{lofdepth}
```

The problem is that both packages define the counters `lofdepth` and `lotdepth`. To prevent the error, simply load `tocloft` with the `subfigure` option; i.e., load the packages like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft} 
\usepackage{subfigure} 

\begin{document}

test

\end{document}
```

By the way, `sufigure` is an obsolete package and shouldn't be used anymore; [`subfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) or [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) are valid alternatives

Comment: Anno 2022 the `subfigure` option to the `tocloft` package appears not to be available.